# XSLFO: Wrap <fo:inline/> at a Specific Length

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, antenna-house

I want to wrap a `<fo:inline/>` if it exceeds a specific length, for example, 10mm. I use the combination of `max-width="10mm"` and `wrap-option="wrap"` attributes. However I cannot get this done. Here is my code:

```
<fo:list-item>
    <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
        <fo:block>1.</fo:block>
    </fo:list-item-label>
    <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
       <fo:block keep-with-next.within-page="always">
            <fo:block text-align="left" text-align-last="left">
                <fo:inline max-width="10mm" wrap-option="wrap">
                    A loooooooooooong text should wrap
                </fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:leader leader-pattern="dots"
                       leader-pattern-width="1mm"
                       leader-length.minimum="2mm"
                       keep-with-next.within-page="always"/>
            <fo:inline max-width="1mm" wrap-option="wrap">
                Another looooooong text should wrap
            </fo:inline>
       </fo:block>
    </fo:list-item-body>
</fo:list-item>
```

It looks like this now:

```
1. A loooooooooooong text should wrap ............... Another loooooong text should wrap
```

I want it to look like this:

```
1. A loooooooooong text 
   should wrap ...................... Another loooooong text
                                                 should wrap
```

Comment: Of course fo:inline-container (should) work for those formatters that support it.  Since you posted Antennahouse, I can only assume you are using it. Otherwise max-width makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fo:inline-container`, as in my https://stackoverflow.com/a/77115126/4092205 answer to your previous question.